# encode a 0-1 matrix from an integer matrix numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So I have an `n*K` integer matrix [*Note*: its a representation of the number of samples drawn from `K-distributions` (K-columns)]

```py
a =[[0,1,0,0,2,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0],
    [3,0,0,0,0,0],
]
```

[*Note*: in the application context this matrix basically means that for the `i` row (sim instance) we drew 1 element from the "distribution 1" (`1 \in [0,..K]`)  (`a[0,1] = 1`) and 2 from the distribution 4(`a[0,4] = 2`)].

What I need is to generate a 0-1 matrix that represents the same integer matrix but with ones(1). In this case, is a 3D matrix of `n*a.max()*K` that has a 1 for each sample that is drawn from the distributions. [*Note*: we need this matrix so we can multiply by our K-distribution sample matrix]

**Output**

```py
b = [[[0,1,0,0,1,0], # we don't care if they samples are stack 
      [0,0,0,0,1,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0]], # this is the first row representation 
     [[0,0,1,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0]], # this is the second row representation 
     [[1,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,0,0,0,0,0]], # this is the third row representation 

]
```

how to do that in NumPy ?
Thanks !

Comment: `(np.arange(1, a.max()+1)[:,None] <= a[:,None]).astype('uint8')`, IIUC

Comment: amazing !! @MichaelSzczesny worked like charm, very creative, post the answer so I can close this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from @michael-szczesny comment

```
a = np.array([[0,1,0,0,2,0],
             [0,0,1,0,0,0],
             [3,0,0,0,0,0],
            ])
b = (np.arange(1, a.max()+1)[:,None] <= a[:,None]).astype('uint8')
```

print(b)

```
array([[[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
```